# XML не работает на андроиде

Tags: android, c#, html, xml, xamarin

Ни `XmlDocument`, ни `HtmlDocument` (из библиотеки [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)) не хотят нормально работать с html страницей. Вот вам пример:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
//document.Load(page);

Console.WriteLine("checkpoint");
```

Здесь все нормально. В консоли спокойно выводится "checkpoint". Но как только я раскоментирую `document.Load(page);`:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.Load(page);

Console.WriteLine("checkpoint");
```

ничего не выводится и вообще, все после `document.Load(page);` как будто исчезает из программы. Почему это происходит?

P.S. В моем WPF приложении на windows все работает нормально.

Comment: `page` какого типа переменная?

Comment: `string`. Содержит весь код страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `page` это строка с кодом страницы, тогда согласно документации надо парсить так:

```
// From String
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Вы же пытаетесь скормить код страницы в метод, который ожидает в строке путь к файлу.